# c# managing messageboxes on form closing

Tags: c#, forms, event-handling, messagebox, sender

I've a parent form with a child form, called by its parent by clicking on a button.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Count() < 1 )
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show(this);
        }
    }
```

On both forms (the parent and the child) I've a messagebox to confirm the closing of the current form.

```
void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {         
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?",
                           "Close application",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }         
    }
```

and

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("You pressed: " + sender);

        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the child form?",
                           "Child form closing",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;              
        }
    }
```

They work good but when I try to close the program, by closing the parent form having the child opened, the closing event on the parent form triggers also the messagebox on the child, so I've to click "Yes i want to close" double: one time on the child one and another on the parent..

How can I manage this situations, so exit the program having one child form opened by closing the parent form?

Comment: you can use global boolean variable like 'closeappasked', and set anywhere  to true if messagebox showed

Comment: I would like to manage the 2 events separately.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducable

Comment: I made 2 forms, called 1 from another, used your code in their `Form-Closing` events... but it actually works like you want.

Comment: The code I posted is a simpler version of the original one.. Dunno why your code works and my code doesn't.. but I guess I need to handle the sender and to check if the sender is the own form or another one..

Comment: @EpicKip using my code, when you have opened the child form and try to close the program by clicking on the X on the parent form, do you fire 1 messagebox only or two? Because this is the problem..

Comment: only 1, I can read... Trust me I tried closing either one first, only 1 messagebox. I tried pressing no and yes too, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by adding the close reason in each FormClosing event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?",
                           "Closing application",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this could help anyone.